# How to execute this PHP script updating a field faster?

Tags: mysql

```
<?
include 'database.php';

$user1 = mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM `users` ORDER BY `id` ASC");


while($user = mysql_fetch_object($user1)) {
mysql_query("UPDATE `pokemon` SET `user`=$user->id WHERE `owner`='$user->username'");
}

?>
```

Basically, I have over 300,000 users in my game, and there are millions of "Pokemon".

I was thinking of using an integer for the foreign key rather than a string, and so I have created this small little script to do that for me.

Unfortunately, it has only seemed to update 1000 users in the past hour, so therefore it would take me 300 hours for the whole thing to be completed. Is there a way I can make this script more efficient?

`user` is the new unique identifier, while `owner` is the old unique identifier (foreign key).

Is there an alternative solution to my method that would require less than 3-4 hours of time? I'm sure there must be some nice little SQL query I can just execute via phpMyAdmin rather than using this code.

Thanks for all the help, it really is appreciated and I will surely return the favour whenever possible.

Edit: Thanks for teaching me this new technique, I'll try it out and update my thread.

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO instead of `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated. [More information avalible here](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Thanks Petr R., looking at its benefits, I guess it's time for me to learn MySQLi and then recode thousands of MySQL queries! :'(

Answer (score 2):

I think an `UPDATE` query with an `INNER JOIN` would be faster than a loop

```
UPDATE `pokemon` a 
INNER JOIN `users` b
ON a.`owner` = b.`username`
SET a.`user`= b.`id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can JOIN the tables and then do the update in a single sql query:

```
UPDATE pokemon
LEFT JOIN users
ON pokemon.owner = users.username
SET pokemon.user = users.id
```